# Heaps with changeable relationship

Tags: heap

A type of data structure very common and very used is the `Heap`. This data structure is characterized by a relationship imposed upon its nodes: if `<` is a relationship and `node` is a node, then `node < node.child` for all the children of the `node`.

But what happens when you need to *change* the relationship?

The brute-force way is simply to extract all elements from the `Heap` and add them to another `Heap` having the desired relationship: usually that takes `O(n log(n))` time. Does it exist a `Heap` that allow to change its relationship in a faster way, possibly with an in-place algorithm?

Comment: You can build a binary heap in-place in an array in O(n) time. So it follows that you can change the relationship and re-order the heap in O(n) time. For an explanation of why that's possible, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/9755721/56778. For a visual example, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947087/build-heap-procedure. For a pseudocode implementation with explanation, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47076465/build-a-min-max-heap-in-on-time-complexity. Or just do a Google search on [build heap O(n)].

Comment: This can be done if the Heap is array-based. What about a tree-based heap?

Comment: It works in a tree-based heap, too. The only real difference is that you'll have to do an initial scan of the tree to build a list of nodes to be moved. That takes O(n) time and requires O(n/2) additional space, but it's still going to be faster than O(n log n).